# PHP Strtotime return date in wrong Date

Tags: php, validation, date

I'm entering this date :

```
$user_entered_date = '30 November, 2020';
```

when i am change date format using this command

```
$new_user_entered_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($user_entered_date) );
```

then result is :

**2018-11-30**

Tell me what is the solution of this problem or where i'm wrong.

Comment: Try '30 November 2020' without the comma

Comment: ^ tested this and it worked

Comment: Seems like comma makes this function think that you meant `20:20:00`. `November 30, 2020` works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is the comma ', ' you have to it without like this:

```
$user_entered_date = '30 November 2020';
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use createFromFormat if you have no control over the input format.

```
$user_entered_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y', '30 November, 2020');
$new_user_entered_date = date_format($user_entered_date, 'Y-m-d');

echo $new_user_entered_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the comma,it ignores the 2020 year and takes 30 November only
The date formed is hence in 2018,use without comma for your answer